# Cannot compare/transform list to float

Tags: python

I have a column "Employees" that contains the following data:

```
122.12 (Mark/Jen)
32.11 (John/Albert)
29.1 (Jo/Lian)
```

I need to count how many values match a specific condition (like `x>31`).

```
base = list()
count = 0
count2 = 0

for element in data['Employees']:
    base.append(element.split(' ')[0])

if base > 31:
    count= count +1
else
    count2 = count2 +1

print(count)
print(count2)
```

The output should tell me that `count` value is 2, and `count2` value is 1. The problem is that I cannot compare float to list. How can I make that `if` work ?

Comment: [mcve] please - including demodata:  `mydata = [ ...... ]`. we would need to guesstimate what your data looks - this is invalid: `invalid_python = 122.12 (Mark/Jen), 32.11(John/Albert), 29.1(Jo/Lian)` - splitting at spaces wont work in the last 2 things - no space in it.

Comment: You need to loop over the values in the list.

Comment: [edit] your question then - add a prefilled dataframe so we can see it. thanks

Comment: data = pd.read_csv(next(iglob('*.csv'))). Data is imported from a csv file, which has a column that contains a value and two names, like 66.66 (Test1/Test2).

Comment: you might want to add the pandas tag as well...

Comment: Formatted data table, fixed code indentation, highlighted code names in text. Assuming that the missing spaces in sampe data is just a typo -- added them.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `df` with a `Employees` column that you need to split into number and text, keep the number and convert it into a float, then filter it based on a value:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Employees': ["122.12 (Mark/Jen)", "32.11(John/Albert)", 
                                 "29.1(Jo/Lian)"]})
print(df)

# split at (
df["value"] = df["Employees"].str.split("(") 

# convert to float
df["value"] =  pd.to_numeric(df["value"].str[0])

print(df)

# filter it into 2 series
smaller = df["value"] < 31
remainder = df["value"] > 30

print(smaller) 
print(remainder)


# counts 
smaller31 = sum(smaller)   # True == 1 -> sum([True,False,False]) == 1
bigger30 = sum(remainder)

print(f"Smaller: {smaller31}      bigger30: {bigger30}")
```

Output:

```
# df
            Employees   
0   122.12 (Mark/Jen)   
1  32.11(John/Albert)   
2       29.1(Jo/Lian)   

# after split/to_numeric
            Employees   value
0   122.12 (Mark/Jen)  122.12
1  32.11(John/Albert)   32.11
2       29.1(Jo/Lian)   29.10

# smaller
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: value, dtype: bool

# remainder
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: value, dtype: bool

# counted
Smaller: 1      bigger30: 2
```